# Azure AD:Powershell script to create roles based on groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a unique requirement, for which I need your help.
The scenario is as follows:
1. We have an app with certain groups assigned to it
2. We need to create a role corresponding to each group. The role name would be the same as the group name.
3. The role should then be assigned to the corresponding group.
4. This needs to be done for all groups assigned to that application (but not all groups in the directory)

From what I understand, the flow of the script would be like:
1. Take application ID as input, and a blank CSV file as input
2. Fetch all groups assigned to the application, based on the application ID. Update the CSV file with the group names.
3. For each entry in CSV, create a new role with the same name as the group name. In the same iteration, assign this role to that group within the application.

I am struggling to make the above script. Can someone help?
Thanks in advance!
3.

Answer (score 1):

Directory role delegation to groups is not currently supported. You can only assign directory roles to users. You would need to manually synchronize group members with role members of a specific role and do this for each user. Refer to the feature request on User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12938997-azuread-role-delegation-to-groups

You may want to use RBAC (rather than directory roles) to control access to resources for directory users and groups. With RBAC, you can assign access to groups and users. The below screenshot shows how to assign access to one Azure AD Group:
[image]